# how to navigate to layout3 from layout2 using an image button

Tags: android, android-layout, imagebutton

I was trying to navigate to Layout2(which is an ImageView), from layout2(contains 8 image buttons), but still I couldn't connect to the desired layout. I guess there is something lagging in the code, but couldn't fetch the missing condition.

The current layout I'm in is explored_homie.xml

Layout2 Java code:

```
setContentView(R.layout.explored_homie);
gallery1 = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.gallery1);

gallery1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
          case R.id.gallery1:
               setContentView(R.layout.gallery_layout);
               break;
         case R.id.upcoming1:
             setContentView(R.layout.rough);
             break;
```

which should call the following layout:
gallery_layout.xml

Layout1 just contains an image button on clicking that, will take me to explored_homie layout2 which again contains 8 imagebuttons and I was trying to access the button gallery(id: galler1) from the above layout2(explored_homie), but still I'm not able to navigate to the desired page, can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: somehow I do not understand a word of your question... could you try to rephrase it more clearly, please?

Answer (score 1):

It's a bad practice to call setcontentview more than once in an activity. The simple approach is to put both layouts in the same xml where one is at visibility gone and when needed switch  the visibility. Off-course this is an ugly way, a more elegant way is to use some sort of view switcher or perhaps the Fragments API (create two fragments one for each layout and use FragmentManager to change the views)

Comment: @Ridcully : see I've three xml layouts.....first is the initial one which will take me to the second xml(explored_homie.xml) and on clicking a particular button(in this case it is gallery1(an image button)) which will take me through to the next page called gallery layout(third layout), which is failing...I'm not able to navigate from layout2 to 3 because of the above mentioned code..there is somethin wrong, which I'm unable to identify...

Comment: Like I stated, you should not use setContentView more than once. This method add the new view to whole window on top of the other without removing them first. The simplest way is to use a viewflipper, or you can add the views pragmatically to a FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

You should use LayoutInfalter class instead doing it.Then if you want to remove view use removeView() method inside your code.